# Search and Add Row on BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

on BigQuery, I am searching for a Query that will allow me to search for a specific value, and add it with a row to my table if it does not exist. Is there a possible way to do this? I currently do know how to search for a value, but if the value does not exist, I'm wondering if there is a Query that will create a new row with the value if it is not there. Any help would be appreciated.. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below example will help you!

```
merge your_table a
using (
  with check_list as (
  select value
  from unnest([1, 3, 5, 7]) value 
  )
  select value from check_list
) b
on a.value = b.value
when not matched then
  insert(value)
  values(value);
```